# Insecure Local Storage in Android

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a native application , where I used to save some values in my `shared Preferences`. But saving values to shared preferences seems to be insecure of security reasons. How can we provide security to values stored in shared Preferences? The penetration testing team can easily access the values stored in the shared preferences. How can we restrain them from accessing the shared preferences?

Comment: Security against what?

Comment: @1615903 - The penetration testing team can easily access the values stored in the shared preferences. How can we restrain them from accessing the shared preferences?

Comment: `The penetration testing team` How does a penetration testing team do that?

Comment: Have a look at EncryptedSharedPreferences on https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data

Comment: @blackapps - they used rooted device to access the shared preferences.

Comment: well i guess the question would be what are you storing on the device that needs to be so secure that the owner of the device shouldn't even access it ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody- yes. exactly!!

Answer (score 1):

> they used rooted device to access the shared preferences

There is no form of storage that is safe against somebody who roots the device. If you have data that rooted device owners cannot have access to, do not have that data on the device — keep it on your server.

Comment: In my case, I'm using MSAL ADb2C as login for native android, which itself saving values  in shared Preferences, which I have no control in it.

Comment: @vinayak: Then do not worry about rooted devices.